# joining same table multiple times in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Hi I am `tuning` one legacy code. we have below 2 tables in a big query.

```
  fnd_currencies, and pa_commitment_txns
```

I have seen in from clause

```
  fnd_currencies fca,
  fnd_currencies fcr,
  fnd_currencies fcp,
  pa_commitment_txns pct
```

first table has been used thrice and it has been outer joined with same `column` with same table.

```
 AND fca.currency_code(+) = pct.acct_currency_code
  AND fcr.currency_code( +) = pct.receipt_currency_code
  AND fcp.currency_code(+) = pct.project_currency_code
```

Can above 3 lines be handled using `fnd_currencies` table only once. is there any smarter way to do that?

Comment: No, at least not easily.  However, your code should be using `LEFT JOIN` rather than that outdated outer join syntax.

Comment: sure..thank you Gordon.

Comment: Might be by using OR but depends on the full query.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Query is extremely complex. So I put this part only. is there any solution looking at the part which i put?

Comment: Try with OR. You have the original query, dropping extra aliases might have side effects.

Comment: Changing it to an `OR` will make things complicated where there's a possibility of `acct_currency_code=receipt_currency_code` etc (although it can obviously be handled). But what's the point, if you're doing the same lookup more than once you won't be doing double the work - you'll take advantage of some caching (and adding the `OR` condition will mean at least the same work will need to be done). What's the problem with the current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ensure that you only query `fnd_currencies` once by using a subquery factoring clause. That would look like this (and keeps @gordonlinoff happy by using ANSI 92 syntax):

```
with ccy as ( select * 
              from fnd_currencies )
select fca.descr as acct_currency
      ,fcr.descr as receipt_currency
      ,fcp.descr as project_currency
      ,pct.*
from pa_commitment_txns pct
left outer join ccy     fca on fca.currency_code = pct.acct_currency_code
left outer join ccy     fcr on fcr.currency_code = pct.receipt_currency_code
left outer join ccy     fcp on fcp.currency_code = pct.project_currency_code
```

Whether this will actually give you an improved execution time depends on the details of your data, which you haven't vouchsafed to us.

Comment: Great answer. got some ideas how can I rewrite the query.thank you so much APC.